# Getting RStudio in Docker Environment Command Window as opposed to browser?

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

This is a question related to using docker to run scripts of RStudio. The problem I'm having is that the person evaluating the results I'm getting wants to have it so that they type in `./test.sh` in the command window, that runs my R script, and a csv of my results prints out to the local directory.

Is it possible to get the rocker rstudio to appear in the command window as opposed to having to log into the browser to use rstudio? It seems all the resources online say something along the lines of put `-p 8002:8787` and `-d` in the docker line of code, but this makes it so you have to go to a local browser to actually run your R script.

I've found this code snippet works, but is there an alternative to using \bin\bash at the end so that the rstudio commands can just stay in the window?

`$ docker run -e PASSWORD=MYPASSWORD -v "$(pwd):/data:ro" -v "$(pwd):/workdir" -it thatguy /bin/bash`

Or, better yet, is there a way to put this docker run command in my Dockerfile so that when I run my `$ docker build` this line just runs automatically?

Comment: why would you need to invoke RStudio to run R scripts from the command line? Why not just use the actual R interpreter?

Comment: The person who wants to run it wants to run it from the command line. Otherwise I agree, I'd rather use the Rstudio software to run it.

Comment: No ... I'm asking why you want to use RStudio ... Just use the `R` interpreter without the Studio. RStudio marketing apparently has gotten so good, that people actually forget it's only an IDE in front of the actual programming language and interpreter named `R`

Comment: You are a hero among us sir, thank you